# SQL Server is removing special character while updating value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran below query

```
update test  
set Fuel = 'BENZIN/ELEKTRIČNI'
where Fuel = 'BENZIN/ELEKTRI?NI'
```

The `Fuel` column is updated with the value BENZIN/ELEKTRICNI instead of BENZIN/ELEKTRIČNI. It removes the special character.

Could anyone help how to retain this special character while updating?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the table schema for `test`, including collations, as text.

Comment: Is `Fuel` an nvarchar or varchar column, if the former, you should use `N'BENZIN...` if the latter, what is the collation?

Comment: yeah it is nvacrchar..N'BENZIN...worked..Thanks